# ubuntu server 18.04 forgets all configuration after fresh install

Tags: server, 18.04, system-installation

I installed ubuntu server 18.04 on a desktop. (plain install nothing fancy)
(US keyboard) (all default settings)

during installation it has received ip from dhcp, i provided hostname username etc. at the end of installation it gave option to 'reboot now'

after reboot when ubuntu server comes up the server name(hostname) shows localhost. after i tried to login with the provided username but it says incorrect login.

I went to recovery mode and reset password : after I logged in it doesnt have any configuration.

The wierd thing is, when i used same image and install it in Virtualbox everything seem to be working fine and normal.

Comment: You probably changed the settings in the Live Session. These won't get transferred to the installation, which is normal.

Comment: I downloaded server iso used a software called RUFUS to make a bootable usb drive, (EFI ) and installed ubuntu server using that usb drive.  I am still confused wher have I gone wrong.